# Postgres pg_rewind will not work with simple use case

Tags: postgresql

We have been struggling to get pr_rewind to work.  In desperation we have been trying to make the use case as simple as possible

We have two databases servers running Postgres 10 on two different machine in the normal Primary/Standby configuration.

Both machines write their WAL archive logs to the same shared drive (called /ice_dev/wal_archive). 
The configuration  has the following terms

```
archive_mode = always
archive_command = 'test ! -f /ice-dev/wal_archive/%f && cp %p /ice-dev/wal_archive/%f'
full_page_writes = on
wal_log_hints = on
```

Checksums are enabled

Our procedure that runs on machine A and B is as follows:

1. Build new databases on A and B, and configure A as Primary and B as Standby databases.
2. Make some changes to the A (the primary) and check that they are replicated to the B (the standby)
3. Promote B to be the new primary
4. Switch off the A (the original primary)
5. Add the replication slot to B (the new primary) for A (soon to be standby)
6. Add a recovery.conf to A (soon to be standby). File contains

   ```
   recovery_target_timeline = 'latest' and restore_command = 'cp /ice-dev/wal_archive/%f "%p"
   ```
7. Run pg_rewind on A – this appears to work as it returns the message *‘source and target cluster are on the same timeline no rewind required’*;
8. Start up server A (now a slave)

At this point A is in a read only mode but not replicating. Its logs contain the following repeating message

```
2018-08-01 20:30:58 UTC [7257]: [1] user=,db=,app=,client= FATAL:  could not start WAL streaming: ERROR:  requested starting point 0/6000000 on timeline 1 is not in this server's history
    DETAIL:  This server's history forked from timeline 1 at 0/57639D0.
cp: cannot stat ‘/ice-dev/wal_archive/00000002.history’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/ice-dev/wal_archive/00000003.history’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/ice-dev/wal_archive/00000002.history’: No such file or directory
2018-08-01 20:30:58 UTC [6840]: [48] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  new timeline 2 forked off current database system timeline 1 before current recovery point 0/6000098
cp: cannot stat ‘/ice-dev/wal_archive/000000010000000000000006’: No such file or directory
```

We can see the 00000002.history file in B’s wal directory…..but it never appears in the wal_archive directory – not even if we issue a checkout or even restart the server.

00000003.history does not appear to exist on either of the machines.

Any ideas what we are doing wrong?

Thanks. Richard

Comment: Did you try setting `recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'` in `recovery.conf`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am currently investigating a similar issue and here is what I've found in [PostgreSQL official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html):

> Normally, recovery will proceed through all available WAL segments, thereby restoring the database to the current point in time (or as close as possible given the available WAL segments). **Therefore, a normal recovery will end with a “file not found” message**, the exact text of the error message depending upon your choice of restore_command. **You may also see an error message at the start of recovery for a file named something like 00000001.history. This is also normal and does not indicate a problem in simple recovery situations**; see [Section 25.3.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-TIMELINES) for discussion.

Therefore, probably the answer is -- you are doing everything right and this is a designed behavior, but there also may be a problem with timelines:

> The default behavior of recovery is to recover along the same timeline that was current when the base backup was taken. If you wish to recover into some child timeline (that is, you want to return to some state that was itself generated after a recovery attempt), you need to specify the target timeline ID in recovery.conf. You cannot recover into timelines that branched off earlier than the base backup.

So you can try to explicitly specify timeline ID in your `recovery.conf`.

Also, I kindly suggest you to better ask at https://dba.stackexchange.com/, since you can get more attention to your DBA-specific question there.